# C# event handler assignment (in CocosSharp), translation to F#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I am trying to translate this C# code please to F#, as I am learning CocosSharp (http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/game_development/cocossharp/first_game/part3/).
I have mistakes either in defining the HandleTouchesMoved properly or assigning it to the touchListener or both.

C# Code:

```cs
touchListener = new CCEventListenerTouchAllAtOnce ();
touchListener.OnTouchesMoved = HandleTouchesMoved;
AddEventListener (touchListener, this);
```

and then HandleTouchesMoved:

```cs
void HandleTouchesMoved (System.Collections.Generic.List touches, CCEvent touchEvent)
{
    //...
}
```

---

MY FAULTY F# CODE (just the relevant piece within the GameScene class):

```
type GameScene (mainWindow: CCWindow) as x = 
    inherit CCScene (mainWindow)

    let touchListener = new CCEventListenerTouchAllAtOnce ()

    do
        // THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM HAPPEN
        touchListener.OnTouchesMoved <- x.HandleTouchesMoved
        x.AddEventListener (touchListener, x)

    member x.HandleTouchesMoved (touches: Collections.Generic.List<CCTouch>, touchEvent: CCEvent) =
        ()
```

The assignment to OnTouchesMoved is faulty apparently - it doesn't compile:
"this function takes too many arguments, or is used in a context where a function is not expected". 
Could be an elementary issue with the assignment that I am missing. What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: And where is the question itself? You brought 3 lines in C# и some in F#. You think it's enough to give the answer, which you want to hear? Why do you use "do"? Sorry for my English

Comment: updated the question with a line at the end. Stating it doesn't compile on the assignment. Which is also what you see as comments in the code itself.

Comment: And do (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483473.aspx) is part of the class constructor. Please correct me if you think I am wrong. Am here to learn. Thanks.

Comment: What compiler error do you get?

Comment: "this function takes too many arguments, or is used in a context where a function is not expected". Obviously its a very elementary issue with the assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, `OnTouchesMoved` is a mutable property of type `Action<_, _>`. In general, F# functions are not the same thing as .NET delegates like `Action`. Now, in some context, F# lets you write a function where a delegate is expected, but not always - so I think in this case you need to be more explicit.

I think (without testing) the following should work

```
touchListener.OnTouchesMoved <- Action<_,_>(fun t te ->
    x.HandleTouchesMoved(t, te))
x.AddEventListener(touchListener, x)
```

You could also just define `HandleTouchesMoved` as a local function (rather than a method) and write something like this:

```
let handleTouchesMoved (touches:ResizeArray<CCTouch>, touchEvent: CCEvent) =
  ()

touchListener.OnTouchesMoved <- Action<_,_>(handleTouchesMoved)
x.AddEventListener(touchListener, x)
```

The `ResizeArray` name is an F# alias for .NET generic mutable list type.

Comment: It works! Though to be honest I am not sure if I really understand the need for the explicit definition of Action<_,_> or why the local function would work without the `fun` and the member has to use it. ... Thank you so much for answering Tomas! I am a big fan :) And grats on the new book. It even got a mention on the TIOBE index as a possible reason for F# going 11th this month.

Comment: Thanks! To add some more info - The local function works without fun because it defines the parameters as space-separated (curried form) while the member uses one argument that is a tuple. You could define member with space too, but it's not that common practice.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I was always very confused about the difference in signature of members as tuples vs local functions, even though the definitions were reading the same (text wise!). I have so much to learn ... thx!

Comment: Added the code to GitHub as an F# (partial) translation to the CocosSharp "BouncingBall" C# tutorial. https://github.com/TalBeno/cocos-sharp-samples-fsharp